# Why is gcov generating gcda files with only the executable bit set when open is wrapped?

Tags: c, gcc, gcov

I have a C project at hand with cmocka tests and it is built using CMake. Now I try to use gcov to determine the test coverage and use this CMake module: https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake 
That module provides a make target which runs the test target executable (which is to run gcov) and then runs lcov and genhtml to generate a report.

Now, the problem is, when the test target is executed, it creates the .gcda files with only the owner's executable bit set, i. e. the read bit is missing. Subsequently, lcov cannot read these files and produces a report with a coverage of 0%. When I `chmod u+r` the gcda files manually afterwards and run the post-test lcov commands by hand, the report is successfully generated (displays something is actually covered). So the gcda files are created and valid, but they have unsuitable permissions set.

The problem seems to stem from wrapping (with ld --wrap) the `open` function for capturing the returned file descriptor in a test case. Here a minimum compiling example:

```
/* wrapped_open.c */

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}

int __wrap_open(const char *filename, int flags)
{
    return __real_open(filename, flags);
}


# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(gcov-mvce C)

add_executable(wrapped_open wrapped_open.c)
target_link_libraries(wrapped_open
    -Wl,--wrap=open
)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH};${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
include(CodeCoverage)

set_target_properties(wrapped_open PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "-g -O0 --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage" 
    LINK_FLAGS "-lgcov --coverage")

setup_target_for_coverage(wrapped_open_coverage wrapped_open "coverage")


# build like this:

cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug # in-source build
make
# receive coverage report like this
make wrapped_open_coverage

# simple gcc command line for compiling (no cmake required)
gcc -g -O0 --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -lgcov -Wl,--wrap=open -o wrapped_open wrapped_open.c
```

When the wrapping of open and the wrap function definition are removed from the linker flags and the code, respectively, it works. But with the files above, the file `wrapped_open.c.gcda` is created with the access mask 0100 and the following is reported by lcov:

`(bulid-directory)/CMakeFiles/wrapped_open.dir/wrapped_open.c.gcda:cannot open data file, assuming not executed`

...resulting in a coverage of 0/4 lines and 0/2 functions.

Why are the access bits wrong when the open function is wrapped like above, even though each path still calls the original function with unmodified parameters (at least that is what it is intended to do)? An obvious workaround would be to modify the cmake module to do the chmod for me, but I would rather like to understand what is going wrong when open is wrapped.

Please tell me in the comments if and which additional information might be required to answer this.

Comment: What is a filesystem (ext4 or other), on which executable and `.gcda` files are created? And it is better to provide simplified CMake script for reproduce your problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The file system is ext4 in a vagrant box (build directory not in the synced folder). I created an mvce and found out in the process that the problem arises when open is wrapped for testing purposes. Thus, I adapted the question accordingly and removed the cmake tag since the problem can be observed even when not building with cmake.

Comment: When creating a file, `open` takes 3 arguments. If you only pass 2 of them through your wrapper, the 3rd argument (file mode) is going to be junk.

Comment: Does that mean I have to provide wrappers for all variants of open if I want to wrap it only for one signature? According to the manpage and the tested code, there is also `open(pathname, flags)` without the mode parameter.

Comment: Generally, `open()` accepts 3 arguments. You can provide 2 of them if `flags` doesn't contain `O_CREAT` flag, so 3d argument has no meaning. But *generally* you doesn't know, whether` O_CREAT` is included into `flags` or not, so you need to use all 3 arguments.

Comment: I see now, what appears to be multiple "kind-of overloads" in the manpage are in fact variable arguments. You see, I am not used C. When I include the third argument in the wrapper, it works as expected. I invite you to post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `open()` is a function with variable arguments. If a file is created, the third argument is the file's mode. In my `__wrap_open` implementation I omitted that third parameter because I did not think of that other code than the code under test would call `open()` as well. Of course, gcov eventually does it to create its gcda files and since I did not specify the third argument to `__real_open`, something undefined went in there for the mode.

So, the solution is to always include all possible arguments in wrapper functions.